# Transitioning from Exchange Server 2007 to 2010

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, exchange-2010, exchange-migration

I have one Exchange 2007 server with all services loaded on it. I want to transition it to 2010 (on another server) and close it out.

What is the best online reference material?
What are the basic task steps for the procedure?
What are the gotchas, if any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, well first thing, your Exchange 2007 server must be at SP2 level, to be able to move your mailboxes to the new server. But, before you do anything here I would ensure you have a full, recent backup of all your Exchange data.

Once that's done, the first thing I would do is get your Exchange 2010 server installed in your organisation and mail flowing between servers, so you can be sure that when you start moving mailboxes, any mail that comes in will end up still getting to any mailboxes that have been moved, and internal mailflow is working ok. I would setup a test mailbox on the new server and make sure everything is working as it should.

Once your happy with that you can begin moving mailboxes over to the new server. Bear in mind the move must be done from the 2010 server (see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638192%28EXCHG.140%29.aspx)). This is an on-line move, so users should not be affected.

One caveat I can think of with Exchange 2010,its got rid of WebDav, so any Entourage clients will need to download the newer EWS capable version of Entourage.

There is an excellent [article here](http://www.networkworld.com/community/node/47778), that gives more detail on the steps for doing this than I have, definitely worth a read.

Comment: Keep in mind that the CAS role has changed too.  Now MAPI clients will connect through a CAS instead of directly to the Mailbox role.  This may change your role sizing compared to 2007, but if you are on single server the resources should actually be less than before.

Comment: Transition went off without a hitch! It was dead simple! Thanks!